# Quick way to regenerate all Java Swing pages in Netbeans?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have a large application with a couple hundred swing pages (java + form files) that I edit in the NetBeans page designer. Most of the pages are years old and haven't been updated after we upgraded Java/Swing/Netbeans versions. The pages still work, but often when a page is "touched" the form designer will change some of the outdated methods or parameters, occasionally causing unintended changes.

What I would like to do is force NetBeans to "regenerate" every page using the up-to-date versions, but without having to manually open each page, do and undo some minor change, save, and then repeat hundreds of times. Is there some way to just tell netbeans to "redraw all?"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that NetBeans offers such a functionality. But as a dirty workaround this might work:

- Select project root node and press `CTRL+H` to open the "replace in project" dialog
- Replace a string that should be included in every file (e.g. `import javax.swing.JPanel;`) with a slightly modified represenation (e.g. `import  javax.swing.JPanel; // additional space)`
- Select the root node again and press `Alt+Shift+F` for "Format recursively". That should remove the extra space again. Or you repeat the search and replace procedure again, if you are afraid of changing other files that you don't want to format.